# Possible to have Silverlight OOB App "Listen" for Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I'm building a Silverlight Out Of Browswer Application with Elevated Permissions and need the ability to basically have the application listen for a keyboard shortcut such as doing something like Ctrl + F10 will cause a window to take focus of the screen... Personally I am against stealing focus but feel that this is alright seeing as the user invokes it themselves.

So more background... if any of you are familiar with applications like XFire or Steam.. I'd like to the ability to do a keyboard shortcut and have a window open above all the other applications like Steam can with the in-game windows.

If Silverlight **can't** do this can someone point me towards a better language where I can create this sort of application?

If Silverlight **can** do this can someone point me in the direction of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight 4 can't do this and Silverlight is not a "Language".  Any application developement platform (JAVA, Delphi, VB6, .NET) that has full access to the windows API could do it.

Silverlight 5 includes support for PInvoke so if your willing to wait for the RC to go to RTM then you may be able to hook the system level WinAPIs needed to watch for a hotkey.